# CKEditor disable auto-editing HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I need in one of my CKEditors to disable autoediting code. If I put this code as HTML:

```
<div class="kontaktJeden">
                <div class="obr">
                    <img src="images/insol.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <table>
                        <tr><td><span class="meno"><strong>Text.</strong></span></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><span class="text">Text</span></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><span class="ico"><img src="images/ico.png" alt="">Text</span></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><span class="dic"><img src="images/dic.png" alt="">Text</span></td></tr>
                <!--         <tr><td><span class="mob"><img src="images/phone.png" alt="">Text</span></td></tr> -->
                        <tr><td><span class="mail"><img src="images/mail.png" alt="">Text</span></td></tr>
                        <!-- <tr><td><a href=""><img src="images/fb.png" alt=""></a><a href=""><img src="images/yt.png" alt=""></a></td></tr> -->
                    </table>
                </div>
```

CKEditor will change it to:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Text.</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img alt="" src="images/ico.png" />Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img alt="" src="images/dic.png" />Text</td>
        </tr>
        <!--         <tr><td><span class="mob"><img src="images/phone.png" alt="">Text</span></td></tr> -->
        <tr>
            <td><img alt="" src="images/mail.png" />Text</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- <tr><td><a href=""><img src="images/fb.png" alt=""></a><a href=""><img src="images/yt.png" alt=""></a></td></tr> -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

automatically. How can I disable it?

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot switch this off. There are reasons why CKEditor reformats your data:

1. It needs to parse it to fix issues, because it needs to have valid source while editing.
2. It needs to process your data, because your data needs to be adapted for editing in `contenteditable`.
3. It passes your data through browser's DOM, so formatting is lost, because DOM does not keep it.

From the source you posted, you only can keep your classes and `divs` (if that was your problem). They are stripped by CKEditor because they are not allowed. Read about the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) which settings you can extend using `config.extraAllowedContent`.

Comment: `extraAllowedContent : "div[*]"` doesn't work. All classes are removed from divs.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by disabling "clean up". Other options (`allowedContent`, `extraAllowedContent`) working only for tags (attributes removing anyway). Version **4.4.5**.

```
allowedContent: true
```

Comment: This should be the real answer.