# How to Disable CKeditor Auto Correction in DNN CMS?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I use DNN 9+ and this CMS use CKeditor.
When I use P or H1-6 or... Tags, CKeditor will remove all classes automatically and also remove empty  tags. 
I want to stop this changes at all. how Can I Disable CKeditor auto correction in DNN portals. whee is Settings in DNN 9.4.1

Comment: For example my html is:
<h1 class="dg-heading text-center font-weight-300 color-white">TEXT</h1>
<p class="pl-25 pr-25 width-60 font-size-sm color-white mb-0">TEXT</p>

But CKeditor will change to:
<h1>TEXT</h1>
<p>TEXT</p>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CKEditor disable auto-editing HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363850/ckeditor-disable-auto-editing-html-code)

Comment: I got some guide by this link, thank you. But I looking for how Setting in DNN CMS? In DNN is different. I try find regarding description on that link.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful as well: https://dnncommunity.org/blogs/Post/2841/Help-DNN-CKEditor-is-cleaning-my-HTML